# Error while deploying job from Command Line in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to execute a command on windows command prompt for deploying a job, but every time it's throwing the same error like below:

> INFO Initializing Job Deployment environment.
> ERROR -metarepository is required.
> ERROR The process will be terminated.

I don't understand I am passing the every detail arguments for the particular command, but why it's not taking the argument is totally shocking.

```
DeployJobs -host "xxxxxx.com" -user "sasdemo" -password "xxxxx" -port 8561 –deploytype deploy –objects "/Shared Data/Marketing/Test_Jen" –sourcedir "E:\sasconfig\Lev1\SASApp\SASEnvironment\SASCode\Jobs\Sourcecodes" –deploymentdir "E:\sasconfig\Lev1\SASApp\SASEnvironment\SASCode\Jobs" –metarepository "Foundation" -metaserverid "A5392QFF.AT000002" -servermachine "xxxxxxxx.com" –serverport 8591 –serverusername "sasdemo" –serverpassword "xxxxxxx" –batchserver "SASApp – SAS DATA Step Batch Server" –folder "/Shared Data/Marketing"
```

The above I am trying to execute from Meta server windows command prompt after navigating to E:\sashome\SASDataIntegrationStudioServerJARs\4.8

I tried to follow the complete note from [here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=etlug&docsetTarget=p1jxhqhaz10gj2n1pyr0hbzozv2f.htm&docsetVersion=4.904&locale=en) but still no luck.

Comment: Thanks james for your response, so if I am not wrong you are referring to remove the double quotes around few argument values. But exactly what argument values need the double quotes removal can you please specify.

Comment: Oh..sorry for the misunderstanding.   [link] (  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=etlug&docsetTarget=p1jxhqhaz10gj2n1pyr0hbzozv2f.htm&docsetVersion=4.904&locale=en)

Comment: I can suggest just try create one sample job in SAS DI Studio, but don't deploy from DI studio, you can run the above command and can check if the same -metarepository error is throwing.

Comment: Hey James, any luck!!!